# How to disable browser service on Win 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, networking

I've been searching around for ways to disable the browser service and cannot seem to find a straight answer. Can someone please provide proper instructions on how to do so.

In addition, is there a way to check if the browser service is running.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Right-click on My Computer and choose Manage
- Expand Services and Applications
- Double click on Computer Browser in the list of services
- Change the Startup type to Disabled and hit Ok

You can also get to Services by clicking the Start button, then Run and typing `services.msc` in the Open box.

The list of services will also tell you if it's running or not.  You can also use the `get-service` command in Powershell to display your machine's services.  For a particular service use the `-name` switch:

```
get-service -name "Computer Browser"
```

To disable it in Powershell:

```
set-service "Computer Browser" -startupType Disabled
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the command line commands: `sc stop “Browser”` to stop the service then `sc config “Browser” start= disabled` to disable it.

Comment: +1 for getting that part in before I edited it into mine :)

Comment: quickdraw mcgraw :)

Comment: +1 for providing a quick answer, I gave the answer to squillman for providing instructions on how to check the status, in addition to disable, enable.  Thank you for your quick response.

Comment: I'd hope you would!  Just wanted to give you options!